# how to plot a network on to a geographic map in R?

Tags: r, spatial

[image]

Hi, I want to get a spatial network like the attach, but I don't know how to make, I have tried ggplot, ggraph, igraph with no nice result.

Could any one like to share some codes or give me some suggustions？

Comment: Please post a representative sample of your data and the code you've tried so far

Comment: the code is too long, please see my answer frame.

Answer (score 0):

I tried ggplot2 method, but raised error （Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'to.lon' not found）.

```
ggplot(chicken_QH, 
       aes(x = from.lon, y = from.lat, xend = to.lon, yend = to.lat)) +
  geom_edges(aes(size = chickenBatchs/10000, 
                 alpha = chickenBatchs/10000,
                 color = type),
             curvature = 0.3,
             arrow = arrow(length = unit(10, "pt"), 
                           type = "closed")) +
  geom_nodes(color = "gold", size = 10, alpha = .5) +
  geom_nodes(color = "gold", size = 3) +
  geom_nodetext(aes(label = from), fontface = "bold") +
  scale_linetype_discrete(guide = F) +
  geom_polygon(data = china_blank, 
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
               fill = "white",
               col = "grey",
               size = rel(.3)) +
  coord_quickmap()
```

also, with the basic plot method, although it does work, but the the polt is quite plain.

```
map(china_blank, asp = 1)
plot(dg_cattle_QH, 
     edge.color = adjustcolor(qc, alpha.f = .7),
     edge.curved = 0.2,
     edge.width = qw,
     vertex.size = 6,
     vertex.color = adjustcolor("gold", alpha.f = .7),
     layout = as.matrix(xy_province_capital_ch[, 3:4]), 
     add = TRUE, 
     rescale = FALSE)
```

[image]